# Build a visual web part that shows a document library

Tags: 2010, development, web-part, document-library

Ok so I need to build a visual web part (Has to be Server side and done in visual studio c#) that shows a document library. On selection of the document library, the web part must output the entire folder structure of the document library

What you guys suggest? I was thinking of using a tree view but I am struggling to figure out how to populate it. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what are the requirements that your web part should meet? As it stands now, it's difficult to understand why you should develop a custom web part instead of using the out of the box ones. Is achieving the tree view display mode your primary need/goal?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx), its a SharePoint version of the ASP.NET GridView. You can't populate that client side, but you may populate a dummy row on the server and the use that as a template for adding additinal rows client side

or use the following link to built tree view webpart

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37530/Document-Library-Tree-View-Web-Part-for-SharePoint

Comment: Hey i meant server side :P... so I will take a look at it thanks.